# How to write group by with add operation in MongoDB Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the following query , I'm doing addition to a field (This field having ISO date as value) then extracting hour from that field, then group by on hour

```
db.campaigns.aggregate([
    {$group : { _id: {$hour:{$add:['$time', 19800000]}}}}
])


Sample record of the collection    

db.campaigns.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c7afdab92be74745af9068"),
    "time" : ISODate("2013-03-08T12:25:24.973Z"),
    "type" : "annoying",
    "PINGS" : 143
}
```

The above one is working fine in Mongo shell,

I'm trying write this query in Java

Here is my partial Java code

```
DBObject group2Fields = new BasicDBObject();
group2Fields.put("hour", new BasicDBObject("$hour", new BasicDBObject("$add",new BasicDBObject("time",19800000))));
DBObject group2 = new BasicDBObject("_id", group2Fields);
DBObject secondGroup = new BasicDBObject("$group", group2);
```

I'm getting "errmsg" : "exception: field inclusion is not allowed inside of $expressions"

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    DBObject group2Fields = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBList addObjects = new BasicDBList();
    addObjects.add("$time");
    addObjects.add(19800000);
    group2Fields.put("$hour", new BasicDBObject("$add", addObjects));
    DBObject group2 = new BasicDBObject("_id", group2Fields);
    DBObject secondGroup = new BasicDBObject("$group", group2);
```

Comment: it's giving "exception: invalid operator '$time'"

Comment: okay I've fixed and ran the query, it should work if all the fields are there.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting calls in your code generally helps you to "visualise" the structure that you want:

```
    BasicDBList addArgs = new BasicDBList();
    addArgs.add("$time");
    addArgs.add(19800000);

    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
        new BasicDBObject("_id",
           new BasicDBObject("$hour",
              new BasicDBObject("$add", addArgs)
           )
        )
    );
```

Which of course produces a `group` variable that serializes like so:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "$hour" : { "$add" : [ "$time" , 19800000]}}}}
```